# How to lock all resources in an Azure resource group with a foreach script

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-resource-lock

I am trying to create a PowerShell script that will put a deletion lock on all Azure resources inside a specific resource group using:

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  1715
```

I can get the current resources in my resource group and format in a table as below

```
$resources=Get-AzureRmResource |Format-Table -property resourcename, resourcetype
```

And here is the output:

```
ResourceName          ResourceType
------------          ------------
georgitestVM          Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
georgitestvm39        Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces
georgitestVM-nsg      Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups
georgitestVM-ip       Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses
georgitest-vnet       Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks
dummyresourcegroup407 Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts
storagedummyaccount   Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts
```

You can also find how the output looks in the attached screenshot [CLICK HERE FOR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXxMf.jpg))

Now I would like to create a lock for each of the 7 resources from the above table but am not sure how to figure out the syntax so that PowerShell can dynamically pipe the values from the table to the parameters of `New-AzureRmResourceLock` cmdlet.

The dummy way to do these 7 locks without looping would be

```
New-AzureRmResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName YouWontDeletegeorgitestVM `
-resourceName georgitestVM -ResourceType Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines `
-resourceGroupName dummyresourcegroup -force -verbose

New-AzureRmResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName YouWontDeletegeorgitestvm39 `
-resourceName georgitestvm39 -ResourceType Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces `
-resourceGroupName dummyresourcegroup -force -verbose

New-AzureRmResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName YouWontDeletegeorgitestVM-nsg `
-resourceName georgitestVM-nsg -ResourceType Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups `
-resourceGroupName dummyresourcegroup -force -verbose

New-AzureRmResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName YouWontDeletegeorgitestVM-ip `
-resourceName georgitestVM-ip -ResourceType Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses `
-resourceGroupName dummyresourcegroup -force -verbose

New-AzureRmResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName YouWontDeletegeorgitest-vnet `
-resourceName georgitest-vnet -ResourceType Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks `
-resourceGroupName dummyresourcegroup -force -verbose

New-AzureRmResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName YouWontDeletedummyresourcegroup407 `
-resourceName dummyresourcegroup407 -ResourceType Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts `
-resourceGroupName dummyresourcegroup -force -verbose

New-AzureRmResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName YouWontDeletestoragedummyaccount `
-resourceName storagedummyaccount -ResourceType Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts `
-resourceGroupName dummyresourcegroup -force -verbose
```

As can be seen, I am looking to fill the `-LockName` parameter with the concatenated values of `("YouWontDelete"+$resourceName)`.
Respectively I am trying to populate the `-resourcename` parameter with the resource name value from the table and finally the `-resourcetype` parameter with the resource type value from the table from the start of my question.

Please recommend a possible syntax to achieve this (to create all the above 7 locks using a powershell foreach loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use this script to create lock to each resource in that resource group, here is the example:

```
$rg = 'jasonauto'
$resources = Get-AzureRmResource | ?{ $_.ResourceGroupName -eq 'jasonauto' } | select -expandpropert resourcename 
foreach($resource in $resources){$ln = 'YouWontDelete' + $resource;
$resourcetype = (Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName 'jasonauto' -ResourceName $resource ).resourcetype;
New-AzureRmResourceLock -LockLevel CanNotDelete -LockName $ln -resourceName $resource -ResourceType $resourcetype -resourceGroupName $rg -force -verbose}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with bash and the azure cli:

```js
az resource list -g myResourcegroup -o tsv --query [].[name,type] | awk '{system("az lock create -t CanNotDelete --notes myDeleteNotes -n myNameOfLock -g myResourcegroup --resource "$1 " --resource-type "$2)}'
```